# Javascript ReferenceError: Security violation on Android Opera

Tags: javascript, android, opera, html5-canvas

I wrote the code as follows in Javascript and it runs well on my laptop. However, when I run it on Android Opera browser, it crashed.

```
window.onload = function() {
... 
   var toDataURL=function(){
     var imageData=[];
     for(var s=0;s<this.height;s++){ 
       imageData=imageData.concat(oCanvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,s,this.width,1).data); //crash here
      }
   ...
   }
...
```

}
It throws the error

Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security violation. 
Error thrown at line 77, column 21 in () in http://www.minh.host48.com/:

```
imageData=imageData.concat(oCanvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,s,this.width,1).data);
```

Could you please tell me what the problem is and how to fix it? Thank you so much

Comment: Loading images from another domain?

Comment: Yes, I load it from my HTML5 page. How to fix it please?

Comment: It is the same origin policy.

Comment: Sorry I understand your idea.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=getImageData+same+origin+policy

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access the context on every single iteration you just need the context once

`imageData=imageData.concat(oCanvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,s,this.width,1).data);`

why not doing

```
var ctx=oCanvas.getContext("2d") for{
imageData=imageData.concat(ctx.getImageData(0,s,this.width,1).data); }
```